# Search in multidimesional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = ['A','B','C','D'];
$array2 = [
   0=>[
     'name'=>'B',
     'number'=>10
 ],
   1=>[
     'name'=>'D',
     'number'=>20
 ]
];
```

I want to compare $array1 with $array2's `name` column.if value of `array1` mathches with `$array2'`s `name` column then corresponding `number` column value will be printed otherwise left empty.

desired output :

```
$array3 = ['','10','','20'];
```

I've tried like this:

```
$array3 = [];

foreach($array1 as $key=>$value){

$array3[$key] = (in_array($value,array_column($array2 , 'name'))) ? array2[$key]['number']  : '';
}
```

It is not working as I'm expecting.how can achieve this?

Comment: How is `array2[$key]['number']` supposed to make sense, considering that your $key goes from 0 to 3, but array2 only _has_ elements under key 0 and 1?

Comment: that is where i'm stucked.any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is `array2[$key]['number']` supposed to make sense, considering that your `$key` goes from 0 to 3, but array2 only *has* elements under key 0 and 1?

Also, missing the $ sign before the variable name there - go and enable proper PHP error reporting, so that PHP can tell you about mistakes like this!

Use `array_search` instead of `in_array`, so you get the *key* of the element found in $array2.

```
foreach($array1 as $key=>$value){
  $array2key = array_search($value,array_column($array2 , 'name'));
  $array3[] = $array2key !== false ? $array2[$array2key]['number']  : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to show that there's more than one way to do this:

```
$array1 = ['A','B','C','D'];
$array2 = [
   0=>[
     'name' => 'B',
     'number' => 10
   ],
   1=>[
     'name' => 'D',
     'number' => 20
   ]
];

$array3 = [];
foreach ($array1 as $letter) {
    $matches = array_filter($array2, function ($element) use ($letter) {return $element['name']==$letter;});
    if (count($matches)>0) {
        $array3[] = array_values($matches)[0]['number'];
    } else {
        $array3[] = '';
    }
}

print_r($array3);
```

`array_filter` is useful if you want to return elements matching some (complex) condition, especially where you have arrays of arrays. Although the matching in this case is quite straightforward.